# Why sometimes vertical centering with height/line-height doesn't work?

Tags: css, fonts, centering

I often encounter a problem with css single line vertical centering using line-height. I usually use this method for buttons. I just set the height and line-height, without padding, like:

```
height: 44px;
line-height: 44px;
```

But sometimes it doesn't center perfectly. See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lm444sny/1/

I was just curious on the reason why it doesn't work. Text is somewhat centered, but not perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the line-height of the font itself. Sone font have more blank pace under so it seems not aligned.

Change the button line-height to 47px or not use at all inside  tag. Chrome for example align text inside button with display flex the best way now for vertical centering.
Take a look at this https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: yes I use flexbox a lot but this is not the case, since the (real project) button is already a flex item to be next to a text field (see the other solved-by-flexbox item :P) so it would be flex item + flex container at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use flex-box instead? You can apply display:flex to the button and the content of it will be a flex-item (in this case a simple text).

Answer (score -1):

it is dependend on vertical-align property. sometimes when you use for example icon fonts the symbols can have various heights.

Best results with vertical centering you can achieve by using flexboxes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: My fiddle doesn't use icons

Comment: This answer would be better if you include a sample code rather than a link-only answer as links can die anytime, rendering your answer useless